# VB.net and mysql return multiple rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How would i return multiple rows that are returned from mysql database from one function to another?

Function that querys mysql is:

```
 Public Function infoSucelje(ByVal username As String)
        Try
            ManageConnection(False) 'Open connection'

            Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT gui_value FROM kerametal.presets"
            Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()


            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read()
                    Return ?????
                End While
            End If

            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        Finally
            ManageConnection(True)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

Second function is the one that should recieve all the strings returned from first one and how can i make loop to check the strings returned and then based on returned strings do something. If function returns strings `buttonCall` and `buttonDisable` for each of those strings i want to run code `w.buttonCall.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` and `w.buttonDisable.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`.

```
 Public Function provjeriDozvoleSucelja(ByVal username As String)
      //for each ?? mysql.infoSucelje(username)
    End Function
```

Comment: You can simply add all the values to a List(of String) and make your function return that list.

Comment: How would i do that based on the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add all the values to a List(of String) and make your function return that list

```
Public Function infoSucelje(ByVal username As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result = new List(Of String)()
    Try
        ManageConnection(False) 
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT gui_value FROM kerametal.presets"
        Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            result.Add(reader("gui_value").ToString())
        End While
        reader.Close()
        return result
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        return Nothing
    Finally
        ManageConnection(True)
    End Try
End Function
```

And call it with

```
Public Function provjeriDozvoleSucelja(ByVal username As String)
     Dim output = mysql.infoSucelje(username)
     For each s in output
         Console.WriteLine(s)
     Next
End Function
```

I assume that your **gui_value** is a field of type string. If not you need to change the List(Of String) to the appropriate datatype and probably you need some check on the value present in the reader....

Comment: Thank you sir! That works perfectly and i will use this to learn about lists in VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it'll help but I do my queries like this...

```
byte x = 0;
Do While reader.Read()
//handle row items
x = x + 1
Loop
reader.Close()
```

Each pass of the reader.read() object will repopulate the reader array with the next row values.  Depending on how you write your SQL query, you just reference each column object directly. If you're doing something like "select x,y,z from table", reader(0) would be x column, reader(1) would be y column, reader(2) would be z column, all of the first row on the first pass...the second row of the second pass, and so on.